# How can I check for differences across multiple columns in different datasets (in R)?

Tags: r

I feel like this may be a common question but I haven't been able to find an answer so far. I have two datasets, one "standard" and one "reference" dataset. In practice, the columns in the standard dataset are used to merge many columns from the reference dataset, simulated here as "xtracols". One thing I need to be able to do is know why the merge fails, if that happens. For example, if I have the two dataframes:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = c(1,2,3),
  batch = c(40,45,42),
  dil = c(100, 1000, 2000)
)

refdf <- data.frame(
  id = c(rep(1, 5), rep(2, 5), rep(3, 5)),
  batch = c(rep(40, 5), rep(41, 5), rep(42, 5)),
  dil = rep(c(1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000), 3),
  xtrcols = rep(c("a", "b", "c"), 5)
)
```

and I merge like this:

```
merged <- merge(df, refdf, by = c("id", "batch", "dil"), all.x = TRUE)
```

I need to know if the merge for a given "id" failed because the batch is incorrect, such as would be the case for id = 2, or if the merge failed because the value for "dil" does not exist in refdf, as would be the case for id = 3. I've tried a few ways of iterating through the dataframes and using match(), but so far nothing has really worked as anticipated.

This would be my anticipated outcome of running the code above. The merge failed for ids 2 and 3, but for different reasons. I'm trying to find a way to know which of those two reasons the merge failed so I can return a specific error message based on that.

[image]

Any insight would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you show your expected output

Comment: @akrun I've added an expected output and clarification the original post. Thanks.

Comment: Isn't this a `left_join` i.e. `left_join(df, refdf)`

Comment: @ akrun yes, that would accomplish the same thing.

Comment: I meant it gives the same expected as your merge as showed in your post.  I see an arrow there, but not clear whether you need to create more columns or not

Comment: @akrun You are correct. I chose merge because I am familiar with it, but this accomplishes the same thing as far as I can tell: left_join(df, refdf, by = c("id", "batch", "dil")) Edit: no additional columns are required, just the join as you've indicated.

Comment: That is correct, but your expected output is not clear i.e whether you want the output like this or just an error and no output?

Comment: @akrun, ah I see. I would need both the merged/joined dataframe as well as some sort of printed output explaining why "xtracols" is NA in the output dataframe.

Comment: You may have to check `library(daff); diff_data(df, refdf)`

Comment: @akrun thanks for the suggestion. I'll look into that and update my post with an answer if I can create one.

Answer (score 0):

Update after changed dataframes:
With the changed dataframes:
Again `anti_join` will help:

```
anti_join(df, refdf, by=c("id", "batch", "dil"))
```

```
  id batch  dil
1  2    45 1000
2  3    42 2000
```

First answer:
We could use `anti_join`: `anti_join()` return all rows from x without a match in y.

```
library(dplyr)

anti_join(df, refdf, by=c("id", "batch"))
```

```
  id batch  dil
1  2    45 1000
```